# Something about my CSS is preventing my image from parallax scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am not sure what but something is preventing my parallax from scrolling properly. I grabed some code online to make a sticky sidebar and believe the problem lies somewhere in there because I have successfully done a parallax before. Here is the imported code.

```
body,html,.row-offcanvas {


height:100%;
}

#sidebar {
  width: inherit;
  min-width: 220px;
  max-width: 220px;
  background-color:#f5f5f5;
  float: left;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  overflow-y:auto;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
#main {
  height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
}

/*
 * off Canvas sidebar
 * --------------------------------------------------
 */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .row-offcanvas {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    width:calc(100% + 220px);
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left
  {
    left: -220px;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left.active {
    left: 0;
  }

  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

Here is the parallax div that I am trying to get to work.

```
.stairsImage
{
  background: url('../images/stairs1.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 37.5em;
 }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a jsfiddle?

Anyway, the "fixed" on your background URL is really suspected

Comment: I attempted to create a codepen (jsfiddle was giving me trouble). However I am not sure how to add an image. So you may have to add your own image. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOVazN